# How to remove a certain folder when tar zipping?

Tags: backup, tar, compression

I want to remove a folder when I'm creating a tar.gz file as it's for a backup and it takes too much space and is not required

I am using the following command;

```
tar -cvzf /home/backups/$STAMP-Earth.tar.gz /home/bukkit/
```

I do not want to include "/home/bukkit/plugins/dynmap" when creating the tar.gz

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: zip != tar.  Please edit s/zip/tar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following option to eliminate the folder/file you want.

```
--exclude=PATTERN
```

Your command becomes like:

```
tar -cvzf /home/backups/$STAMP-Earth.tar.gz --exclude=plugins/dynmap /home/bukkit/
```